# Netbean's Project Structure

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I am using Netbeans for quite a while, But still I am not familiar with the Netbeans's project structure and other things like Ant, Maven, different xml files, manifest etc etc.

Can anyone redirect me to any other resources or any book that's gonna give me a very basic insight about what all of this things means and how they all fit together.

**EDIT** I have googled about each topic but, they give me an idea about what they are. But, I dont understand how they fit together.

Say, in A NB project, there are 4 items, inside the project folder

- nbproject  (folder)
- src (I understand this hold just the packages in a folder-ed fashion)
- build.xml
- manifest.mf

I dont understand, what this build.xml and manifest.mf file does

inside nbproject

- private (hold netbeans preference info)
- build-impl.xml
- genfiles.properties
- project.properties
- project.xml

I guess these xml files are some sort of a script, but how they work and when, what the feed into is unknown to me.

Comment: This is a very broad question. I would consider narrowing it down. What exactly is it about Ant, Maven and Manifest you don't understand?

Comment: Also if you want a insight into each, look at the info pages attached to each Tag on this site. If you hover over, for example, the java tab in your question you will see an "info" option, click that to get a good background on each that you wish to learn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**build.xml** - Contains instructions to build your application. You need to learn about Ant to understand the content.

**manifest.mf** - Is information that will end up in the jar produced as part of compiling your project. You need to search Java documentation for more explanation. Typically, you don't need to fiddle with these files.

**project.properties project.xml** - These contain general information about your project in NetBeans (i.e., things which are not really related to the compilation process -> Preferences, etc...).

In general, you don't need to worry about these files. NetBeans takes care of them.

Comment: what about *build-impl.xml* & *genfiles.properties*. What exactly happens when I build for debug or release build?

Comment: These files are automatically generated by NetBeans from the files I mention in my answer. They are a kind of derivative of them. I guess it facilitates NetBeans' job.